# Calculating percentages for each month in R

Tags: r

I have the following data set with two million observations. The data is for the period April 2008 to April 2010.

```
> head(df)
               Empst Gender Age Agegroup   Marst                         Education State Year Month
1           Employed Female  58    50-60 Married  Some college or associate degree    AL 2008    12
2 Not in labor force   Male  63      61+ Married   Less than a high school diploma    AL 2008    12
3           Employed   Male  60    50-60  Single  Some college or associate degree    AL 2008    12
4 Not in labor force   Male  55    50-60  Single High school graduates, no college    AL 2008    12
5           Employed   Male  36    30-39  Single  Some college or associate degree    AL 2008    12
6           Employed Female  42    40-49 Married       Bachelor's degree or higher    AL 2008    12
  YYYYMM   Weight
1 200812 1876.356
2 200812 2630.503
3 200812 2763.981
4 200812 2693.110
5 200812 2905.784
6 200812 3511.313
```

I want to calculate and plot the monthly unemployment rate. To calculate the unemployment rate I divide the sum of weights of unemployed by the the sum of weights of employed and unemployed:

```
    sum(df[df$Empst=="Unemployed",]$Weight) / 
    sum(df[df$Empst %in% c("Employed","Unemployed"),]$Weight)
```

To calculate the monthly unemployment rate I use the for loop:

```
UnR<-vector()
for(i in levels(factor(df$YYYYMM))){
  temp<-sum(df[df$Empst=="Unemployed" & df$YYYYMM == i,]$Weight) /
        sum(df[df$Empst %in% c("Employed","Unemployed") & df$YYYYMM == i,]$Weight)
  UnR<-append(UnR,temp)
  rm(temp)
}
```

My question is: Is there another way of calculating the unemployment rate by month using apply or something of the sort? Thanks. Below is the summary of the data set in case you need it. Let me know if more clarification is necessary.

```
    Empst            Gender             Age         Agegroup          Marst        
 Not in universe   :  11423   Male  :1266475   Min.   :16.00   16-19:187734   Married:1441114  
 Employed          :1600882   Female:1377638   1st Qu.:31.00   20-29:422699   Married:      0  
 Unemployed        : 132344                    Median :45.00   30-39:431298   Single :1202999  
 Not in labor force: 899464                    Mean   :45.81   40-49:490533   Single :      0  
                                               3rd Qu.:59.00   50-60:518633   Single :      0  
                                               Max.   :85.00   61+  :593216   Single :      0  

                             Education          State              Year          Month       
 Less than a high school diploma  :418636   CA     : 221244   Min.   :2008   Min.   : 1.000  
 High school graduates, no college:802141   TX     : 132650   1st Qu.:2008   1st Qu.: 4.000  
 Some college or associate degree :719492   NY     : 114282   Median :2009   Median : 6.000  
 Bachelor's degree or higher      :703844   FL     : 106116   Mean   :2009   Mean   : 6.385  
                                            PA     :  82482   3rd Qu.:2009   3rd Qu.: 9.000  
                                            IL     :  80816   Max.   :2010   Max.   :12.000  
                                            (Other):1906523                                  
     YYYYMM           Weight     
 Min.   :200804   Min.   :    0  
 1st Qu.:200810   1st Qu.: 1176  
 Median :200904   Median : 2496  
 Mean   :200887   Mean   : 2226  
 3rd Qu.:200910   3rd Qu.: 3139  
 Max.   :201004   Max.   :16822
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) package, specifically ddply? You'd throw the data frame into that, pivoting on unique timestamp. So you'd get something like:

```
unemployment_rate.df <- ddply(.data = df,
                              .variables = "YYYYMM",
                              .fun = function(x){
                                return(sum(x$weight[x$Empst== "unemployed"])/sum(x$weight[|x$Empst== "Not in labor force"]))
```

What this should do is go through the dataset for each unique yearmonth combination and perform the unemployment calculation, returning a dataset that looks like:

```
YYYYMM V1
200812 0.13
200901 0.1
200902 0.43
```

If the goal is speeding up your for-loop, another way of getting to it (you should apply this to for-loops generally) is specifying the length of the output vector beforehand, if you know it. So, to use this example, you know you'll have an output vector of the same length as unique(df$YYYYMM) - so if you specify that in advance, then the loop should move faster, because R is no longer having to expand the vector each iteration - it just modifies an existing (blank) element.

You can also avoid having to assign/append this way, which that *also* occupies time - the R session has to cut some space out for temp each iteration - by just assigning to output_vector[i]. So, with this example, you'd get something that looks like.

```
#Create an output vector. We can specify length, because we know there'll
#be one entry for each unique value in the YYYYMM column.
#That saves time because it means R just modifies the vector in place.
UnR <- numeric(length(unique(df$YYYYMM))

#And now, the for loop.
for(i in levels(factor(df$YYYYMM))){

  #Instead of creating a temporary object (which takes time), and then appending
  #(which takes time), we can just assign the result to the Ith element of the
  #output vector.
  UnR[i]<-sum(df[df$Empst=="Unemployed" & df$YYYYMM == i,]$Weight) /
        sum(df[df$Empst %in% c("Employed","Unemployed") & df$YYYYMM == i,]$Weight)
}
```

That should be a lot faster. Plyr may be faster than that (I haven't benchmarked it), but these sort of for-loop improvements are generalisable, so I thought I'd take the time to wax lyrical on them. When people say for-loops in R are slow, they mean "for loops with output of unknown length are slow" or "for loops with non-primitive datatypes are slow" - and they're right. But for operations like this, it's perfectly possible to make a performant loop.

Comment: You may use `summarise` in your `ddply` call, to avoid all the `x$`

Comment: Surely the presence of non-considered data would be a problem there? ("Not in labor force")

Comment: See the analogous code in @shujaa's `dplyr` `summarize`.

Comment: @Ironholds what do you mean? For the calculation of the unemp rate the "not in labor force" population is not considered. Was you referring to the possibility that the code in the answer produces wrong results by not considering the "not in labor force"?

Comment: Nono, I was replying to Henrik's comment - that the summary would include 'not in labour force' since those entries are in each subset :).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `dplyr`, somewhat similarly to the `plyr` method.

```
require(dplyr)
df %.%
    group_by(YYYYMM) %.%
    summarize(UnR = sum(Weight[Empst == "Employed"]) /
                    sum(Weight[Empst %in% c("Employed", "Unemployed")]))
```

`dplyr` will almost certainly be faster than `plyr`, but you may not notice a difference unless your data are quite large.

Comment: dplyr is preferred to plyr these days, yep :). I'm rather plyr-centric at the mo because debian-based systems haven't got R3 yet. Bah.

Comment: It's always good to have options :). Let's see if someone posts a data.table solution...

Comment: @Ironholds I have R3 under ubuntu.

Comment: Huh; which ubuntu version? I don't on xubuntu, or on our servers (which run LTS. Bah.)